# Как настроить ЧПУ в YII

Tags: yii, чпу

Здравствуйте, есть ссылка

```
http://localhost/index.php?r=page/index&name=about
```

хочу чтоб ссылка отображалась как

```
http://localhost/about
```

Написал в config

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
         '<name:\d+>'=>'page/index',
        ),
)
```

И в результате все ссылки в меню изменились,  но только вот открывает "неверный url", как достичь результата, подскажите что-нибудь?

Comment: ну хватит уже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не является верной ссылкой, потому что вы сообщили фреймворку, что ждете цифру ('=>'page/index')

читайте про regExp

Answer (score 2):

- [Человекопонятные URL](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/ru/final.url)
- [ЧПУ в YII или urlManager](http://snippets.su/topic/280/chpu-v-yii-ili-urlmanager/)

Answer (score 1):

### в корне создаем\переписываем .htaccess

```
Options Includes FollowSymLinks
#hide index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

---

в config\main

---

```
// uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false, 
    'rules' => array(
            // стандартное правило для обработки '/' как 'site/index'
        '' => 'site/index',
        // это пример добавления который заработал
        //'secondcontroller/<action:.*>'=>'secondcontroller/<action>',
        'user/<action:.*>'=>'user/<action>',
        //'<action:.*>'=>'site/<action>', //закомментил а то глючило с ним
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Перенес .htaccess в /web заработало, из корня не хотело